# Cannot convert string '@bool/some_key' to target class 'boolean'

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-resources

I have the following `bool.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="some_key">false</bool>
</resources>
```

When I try to use this value in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.SomeActivity"
    android:enabled="@bool/some_key"
    ... >
    ...
</activity>
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert string '@bool/some_key' to target class 'boolean'

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Where is `bool.xml` in your project?

Comment: @CommonsWare under res/values/bool.xml

Answer (score 5):

The code looks fine.This is the issue of Android studio 2.x .It is fixed in 2.3 .Please refer [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223574).If you still need to get this done use 2.3 canary instead [get 2.3 canary](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23canaryavailable)